# Windows batch-file wmic to get PID of a java process, how do I set tokens to a variable to test if PIDs exist? - start if not,else prompt for restart

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, wmic, pid

**Operating System: Windows 7

Process concurrency locking: java Thread**

I'm creating a bat file that works like a lock.
To check whether the process exists, I perform the following:

```
cmd /c wmic process where(name="java.exe") get ProcessID^,commandline| for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr "Thread"') do set pid=%%a
```

**Relevant observations:**

I am positive **%%a** is being populated, and I just figured out the set **pid=%%a** is actually being run on the cmd-line, rather than setting the variable.  
*I updated my overly verbose title to reflect this realization.*

Specifically, I just need to set a variable to tell me whether or not a **processID exists** from the wmic return. (simple as 0/1)

THE RETURN (pid changes of course):

**name/commandline/processID**

```
java Thread 10144
```

**Clearer question**
How may I alter or add to my code above to have %%a actually store its data in a variable? 
Currently %pid% is not being populated due to it running:

```
set pid=%%a
```

as a console command instead of performing the assignment.
 I'd also like to know how to deal with how to test if the assignment is valid:
 Should I use 'if exists', or a certain comparator, such as:

```
if "%pid%" != "" ( start "" ./newProcess.bat )
```

**UPDATE**
From what I've read @set will work, but no dice here: still an empty %pid% with the above attempt.  I've been trying out variants where the entire command is within the tokenizing for-loop, I just can't seem to strap this boot around the extremely finnicky escapes required when using wmic with Windows bat files.  **Any syntax champions able to scry my errors in the following code?**  I would be extremely grateful.

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('wmic process where^(name="java.exe"^) get ProcessID^,commandline^|findstr "Thread"') do @set pid=%%a
```

**Solution:**

The primary issue is escaping all of the characters; wmic used in batch files often requires a lot of caret ^ escapes.  I had missed the ^=.  Lesson learned.  Nesting the entire statement was key to getting pid set to the token.  Many sources hinted at using @set pid=%%a, though that did not work for me.

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('wmic process where ^(name^="java.exe" ^) get ProcessID ^,commandline ^| findstr "Thread"') do set pid=%%a
```

In future batch scripting, I'm going to take a friend's solid advice and use Powershell.  Being able more readily parse and loop, and use Get-Help (similar to man pages) are a couple of reasons.

ps - Please don't barbecue me as this is my first post here.  I encourage post critiques in order to improve.

Comment: You explain what you're doing, but Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: How may I alter or add to my line above to have %%a actually store its data in a variable?<br><br>

Currently %pid% is not being populated due to it running: <br>
set pid=%%a <br>
as a console command instead of performing the assignment.<br>

I'd also like to know how to deal with how to test if the assignment is valid:<br>
Should I use 'if exists', or a certain comparator, such as:

if "%pid%" != "" ( start "" ./newProcess.bat )  ?

Comment: @RaGe apologies for my formatting (noting response I forgot to tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote just another token, and I'm sure you need to skip the first line of wmic's output (the header). Otherwise, you assign blanks to the variable:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=3" %%a in ('wmic process where ^(name^="java.exe"^) get ProcessID^,commandline ^| findstr "Thread"') do set pid=%%a
```

The changes: a blank just behind 'where', a quoting caret just before '=', and the 'skip=1' in the FOR loop. 
**edit:**
According to OP, using `@set pid=%%a` didn't work, but `set pid=%%a`. This is reflected now in the above code.

If you could comment how to create threads ad hoc I could test this better, as I don't see any threaded processes on my PC at the moment.

Comment: This didn't work out of the box, but it was really close!  I'm not completely sure of the reason it doesn't like the @set.  Without the @ it worked, and the spacing before the carats didn't seem to matter too much, so long as they were present.

Comment: On the threaded processes I just made a ThreadFoo.java text file with a `
`public class ThreadFoo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter text");
int myInt = in.nextInt();
in.close();
}
}'  then ran cmd>javac ThreadFoo

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)   Running ThreadFoo.class from within the bat (include path to ThreadFoo if needed):
`start "WindowName" "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /k java ThreadFoo`

Comment: Forgot to mention, the main one I missed was the escape on =   -thanks again.